# JavaScript scroll to y position

Tags: javascript

does anybody know why scrolling of scrollbar to y position does not work? Very simple code below. In JSFiddle it works fine. I don't see any reason why it should not work. Scroll bar appears but still at the top :-(

```
<script>
 window.scrollTo(50,100);
</script>

<body>
    <div style="width:200px; height:1500px;background-color:blue;">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<script>` element at the bottom of the page, before the end of `<body>`?

Comment: Your script is executed before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the script block below the div and attach the scrollTo to the windows onload event for this to scroll down on page load.

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="width:200px; height:1500px;background-color:blue;">
        hello
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() { window.scrollTo(50,100); };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, your're right, thanks :) I have corrected the code now.

Comment: Adding a Listener and also moving the script tag to the bottom is redundant. Do either one is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Script must be executed after all DOM elements are created so use window.onload method for javascript and $(document).ready() for jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            window.scrollTo(50, 100);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:200px; height:1500px;background-color:blue;">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or shortcut: `$(function(){ })`.

Comment: Thank you all, that was the problem :-)